Does there exist a similitude matrix $S$ verifying equation $S^{20}+23S=S_0$

Does there exist $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t $$\begin{pmatrix} a& -b\\ b &
 a\end{pmatrix}^{20}+23\begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b &
 a\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 20 & -23 \\ 23 & 20\end{pmatrix}.$$

I already proved that $$\begin{pmatrix}a& -b\\ b & a\end{pmatrix}^n=\begin{pmatrix} r^n\cos n\phi & -r^n\sin n\phi\\ r^n\sin n\phi & r^n\cos n\phi\end{pmatrix}$$
where $a+bi=r(\cos\phi+i\sin\phi)$.
I'm stuck at solving the equations $$\begin{cases}r^{20}cos 20\phi+23r\cos\phi=20\\ r^{20}\sin 20\phi+23r\sin\phi=23.\end{cases}$$
Could someone help me solve the equations? Thanks in advance!

What can you say about Jordan cell of the LHS and RHS?

This is equivalent to asking if there is a $z\in\mathbb C$ such that $z^2 + 23z = 20 + 23i$. Then the answer is that yes, there are 20 such $z$ (counting multiplicities) since every polynomial of degree $n$ has $n$ roots in $\mathbb C$ (counting multiplicities).

@MPW: No guarantee that there is a real root.

For what it's worth, Wolfram Alpha gives the following (approximate) solution, along with 19 others.
$$
a = -1.219910131834606, \quad b = - 0.027890573825179
$$

To expand the comment of @MPW, the form of your matrices are a representation of complex numbers $z=a+ib$, so your entire first equation is represented by $z^{20}+23z=20+23i$. It doesn't matter if the roots of this equation are real or not, because complex roots will be represented by your real 2x2 matrices

@Piquito : That doesn't matter. Remember, a root $a+bi$ is real iff $b=0$. The values $a$ and $b$ are always real.

In my original comment, note "$z^2$" should have been "$z^{20}$" (typo).

@MPW: Everybody has noted this (it was not important this typo)

Initial matrix representation :
$$\begin{pmatrix} a& -b\\ b &
 a\end{pmatrix}^{20}+23\begin{pmatrix} a & -b \\ b &
 a\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 20 & -23 \\ 23 & 20\end{pmatrix}$$
Is equivalent, by a classical isomorphism :
$$(a+ib)^{20}+23(a+ib)=\underbrace{20+23i}_{z_0}$$
otherwise said :
$$z^{20}+23z-z_0=0\tag{0}$$
This equation has $20$ complex roots. In fact, if we neglect the first degree term $23z$, we are close to the $20$th roots of $z_0$.
Here are graphical representations showing



that there are $20$ roots to the system of equations and




that these roots are close to the $20$th roots of $z_0=20+23i$.



but apparently without simple solutions.
$$\begin{cases}\text{In blue : }&r^{20}\cos (20\phi)+23r\cos\phi&=&20\\ \text{In red : }& r^{20}\sin(20\phi)+23r\sin\phi&=&23.\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

Fig. 1 : The representation of the two implicit functions (red and blue curves) and there $20$ intersections in $(r,\phi)$ coordinates for $0<r<2$ and $-\pi<\phi<\pi$.

Fig. 2 : Position of the roots in the complex plane (coordinates $(x,y)$) in black, attesting the close vicinity with most of the $20$th roots of $z_0=20+23i$ in red along the circle with center $(0,0)$ and radius $\sqrt[40]{20^2+23^2}$.
SAGE program :
 var('r t z M')
 M=2
 f1(x,y)=r^(20)*cos(20*t)+23*r*cos(t)-20
 g=implicit_plot(f1,(r,0,M),(t,-pi,pi))
 f2(x,y)=r^(20)*sin(20*t)+23*r*sin(t)-23
 g+=implicit_plot(f2,(r,0,M),(t,- pi,pi),color='red')
 f=CC['z'](z^20+23*z-(20+23*I))
 rts=f.roots(CC,multiplicities=False)
 for s in range(len(rts)) :
    z1=rts[s]
    r=abs(z1)
    a=arg(z1)
    show([z1,r,a])
    g+=point([r,a],size=20,color='black')
    g+=point([real(z1),imag(z1)],size=20,color='black')
 show(g)


See a graphical representation close to Fig. 1 here
